# How can I revive a wilted Mexican feather grass?

Tags: plant-health, grass

I bought a [Mexican feather grass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nassella) from the clearance section so I know it's been taken care of, it's just a little droopy so it was heavily discounted. Since I thought I'd like it, I'd love to be able to get it to perk up. Right now it looks like a pony tail that's partly green, partly tan. My friend thinks it looks like Lady Gaga buried feet first. Hopefully it's not too late.

[image]

Any ideas on how I can revive it?

Comment: "from the clearance section so i know it's been taken care of" I do not believe this is a logical conclusion.

Comment: It's watered . It's fertilized.  This particular one just didn't get as much. It's not dead just droopy.

Comment: One might hope they wouldn't put actual dead plants in the clearance section.... but anything there has usually NOT been cared for, may need planting out or repotting, or has a problem, or its the end of the season for that particular plant,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean Nassella tenuissima 'Ponytails' - you haven't said what you intend to do with it, but I'm assuming its going outside, so plant it somewhere that's free draining but doesn't constantly dry out completely. Keep it watered initially until its settled in. If you're not putting it outside, turn it out of its pot and check whether it needs a larger container. Needs free drainage, so a container with holes is essential and don't leave it sitting in an outer tray or pot in water. Either comb or pull out dead brown parts, or cut it right down and let it grow again. Can be cut in April, and again in Fall.

Hopefully, this plant was in the clearance section only because it needs cutting back and may need repotting - if they cut it back, they're unlikely to get a buyer for it, so its not worth the effort to tidy it up. Either that or its one from last year that they've not tended this spring.

Comment: I planted it on the corner of my patio. It said it likes full sun and it pretty much will get it there. There's a tree near it but it's not super bushy. It's more green in the center but a lot of it is tan. I'm expecting it to stand up but I'm thinking maybe the tan parts should be cut off so the green can stand up. Looks like a blonde wig sitting on the ground right now. But it's only been about a half of a day since I planted it. I'm wondering if I tie it up loose around a stick to get it standing would help.

Comment: Cut it - shouldn't be 'blonde' at this stage, should be green, top parts go 'blond' later.... and this grass is a bit like a fountain to look at when grown well, splaying out and drooping over, so not only will a stick not help the plant recover, it'll look absolutely awful...

Comment: I added a picture of it. It's green but more center. I'll trim it back this evening.

Comment: Take the shears to it and cut it right down, keep it watered. Most of that growth is dead, but cutting it back and looking after it should mean it grows again quite rapidly. It'll be next to impossible to trim out the dead parts once new growth starts, if you don't cut it all off.

Comment: Thank you. Kinda sad for that but will be excited to see it perk up. Looked really cool on the label. Plus this isn't some big investment. Just saving one plant at a time.

Comment: Also, if the leaves (??) are tan (and green), but the roots are white...it definitely is mostly alive right?

Comment: I see some traces of green, so lets hope it's not too far gone... certainly worth trying by cutting it back and coddling it a bit....